# What's the difference between “scenario to load data from” set to a dynamic scenario variable and “compare against scenario” set to a scenario array?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-scenarios

I'm looking to understand more about dynamic scenario variables and scenario arrays in my Scenario.

What's the difference between “scenario to load data from” set to a dynamic scenario variable and “compare against scenario” set to a scenario array in Foundry Scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Scenario to load data from` is always a single scenario, whereas the comparison scenarios allow displaying values from multiple scenarios.

Notably, only the table and chart widgets support comparison scenarios while just about every widget that has scenario support has the notion of loading data from a single scenario.

There is some nuance in the tables and charts where the scenario to load data from drives what objects appear in the table and in what order. E.g., if you’ve added an object in a scenario and you are using that scenario as a comparison scenario, you will not see the created object in the table because it doesn’t exist in the scenario to load data from.

If you want to view newly created or deleted objects reflected in what loads in the table, you should configure that scenario as the scenario to load data from.